# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The sum again is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$$
It looks like it should be amenable to some modification to get towards the exponential power series or something close to it, But I really can't get anything to pop out.

Wolfram alpha says it sums to 1/2 and my friend verified this by partial sums but I am curious if there is a slick way to evaluate this, maybe something like partial fractions that can deal with the factorial or a product rule type thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}xe^xdx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}dx$$
$$1=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$$
$$1=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$$

so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: How is this answer different from the one posted one hour earlier by @stevenstadnicki ?

Comment: @Dr.MV The reason I accepted it instead of the also very helpful ones posted by you and steven is the care taken with the definite integration. I think it is easier to avoid errors with indefinite integration.

Comment: FWIW, I never suggested specifically definite or indefinite integration; the reason mine is spelled out in less detail is that it was meant to be closer to a hint or outline than a complete top-to-bottom answer.

Answer (score 15):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}$$

Comment: I can definitely take it from here, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. -Mark

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you my friend!!

Comment: @E.H.E Very much appreciative.

Answer (score 4):

Work via generating functions: $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$, so $xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n!}$.  Now integrate this with respect to $x$; you should find that the RHS becomes $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}$ (and the LHS is easily integrable by parts).  Finally, set $x=1$ (and note that your sum starts at $n=1$ and not $n=0$, so there's a term from this series that you're missing).

Comment: fantastic, I should have seen that. Thank you!

Comment: Very nice idea. +1